# Cannot return from recursive algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

Im studying algorithims and data structures in python and came across the prefix averages problem. Where i have to return a sequence A where A[j] is the average of elements S[0]+S[1]+...S[j] of another array S.

I have solved it iteratively and attempted a recursive solution which works only when i use print to display the result from inside the function. If i try to use return to return the result and use print outside at the function call, i get None

```
#iterative solution
def prefix_average(nums):
    A = []
    for x in range(1,len(nums)+1):
        prev = nums[:x]
        average = sum(prev)/len(prev)
        A.append(average)
    return A

print(prefix_average([2,3,4,2,6,7]))

#recursive solution
def prefix_average_recursive(nums):
    def helper(A = [],value=1):
        if value == len(nums)+1:
            return A
            #returns None, however works properly when called with print()
        else:
            prev = nums[:value]
            average = sum(prev)/len(prev)
            A.append(average)
            helper(A,value+1)
    helper()

print(prefix_average_recursive([2,3,4,2,6,7]))
```

Why cant i return from within the recursive function?
----------EDIT: NOOB MISTAKE-------------

```
#recursive solution- works great

def prefix_average_recursive(nums):
    def helper(A = [],value=1):
        if value == len(nums)+1:
            return A
            #returns None, however works properly when called with print()
        else:
            prev = nums[:value]
            average = sum(prev)/len(prev)
            A.append(average)
            return helper(A,value+1)
    return helper()
```

Comment: As your code is currently written you can't return from the `else` statement, because you don't have a `return statement` there.

Comment: You can, you just don't.

Comment: Notice how `prefix_average_recursive` does not return the result of `helper()` on the last line?

Comment: Im still not quite clear on the hints you are giving me... Im a beginner in python also :)

Comment: Oh, i see it now